Dynamically changing the band based on aggregate chosen from slicer
There is a table named customer alarms, we have customers, alarm duration and count of alarm against every alarmduration



Customer
AlarmDuration
CountofAlarm




C01
15m
3


c01
15m-3h
4



There is a separate table named AlarmBands that has values 0, 1-5,6-10, 10+
which specify the band based on count of alarms



AlarmBands




0


1-5


6-10


10+



there is a filter that has alarmduration (15m, 15m to 3h,3h to 7h,7h+)
this is the same column we have in customer's table
based on the values selected from the filter, it should sum up the customers alarms and then choose a band value from AlarmBands table.
For example: Customer C01 has 3 alarm of 15m and 4 alarms of 15mto 3h duration
when the user selects 15m from the filter. this customer should be counted in band 1-5 because there were 3alarms of 15m and 3 lies in between 1-5
but if the user selected 15m and 15m-3h (both) from filter. Total alarms =7, so this customer should be counted in band 6 to 10
I am unable to achieve this in power BI. Any leads on it would be of great help
I need AlarmBands on X axis and count of customers on Y axis. connected to a filter of Alarm Duration
I have tried to accomplish it with the below dax
Measure= 
var _a1=ALLSELECTED('Table'[AlarmDuration])
var _a2= SUMMARIZE(CALCULATETABLE('Table',FILTER('Table',CONTAINSROW(_a1,'Table'[AlarmDuration]))),'Table'[Customer],"CountOFAlarm",SUM('Table'[CountofAlarm]))
var _a3=ADDCOLUMNS(_a2,"AlarmBand", IF([abc]=0,0,[abc]>=1 && [abc]<=5,"1-5",[abc]>5 && [abc]<=10,"6 to10","10+"))
var _a4= COUNT(_a2[{Customer],USERELATIONSHIP(_a3[AlarmBand],ALrmB[AlarmBand]))

Detailed Image of Expected Output Attached

you can try to create a alarmband table like below.

then create a measure
MEASURE =
VAR _list =
    DISTINCT ( 'customer alarms'[AlarmDuration] )
VAR _tbl =
    SUMMARIZE (
        FILTER ( 'customer alarms', 'customer alarms'[AlarmDuration] IN _list ),
        'customer alarms'[Customer],
        "total", SUM ( 'customer alarms'[BandwiseAlarmCount] )
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER (
            _tbl,
            [total] >= MAX ( 'AlarmBands'[Left] )
                && [total] <= MAX ( AlarmBands[Right] )
        )
    ) + 0



Hi Ryan,
Thanks for the response. But what I actually need is, measure should return the count of customer.
For example, in your above snapshot, when I select 15m, measure should display 1 infront of 1-5 Band because we have 1 customer having total alarms count (i.e; 3) value between 1-5
and when I select 15m and 15m-3h both, measure should display 1 infront of 6-10 band. Where 1 shows we have customer whose total alarms lie in between 6-10 band value

@https://stackoverflow.com/users/25265867/ryan
I have attached the image of expected output above in my post for your reference

updated the answer, pls have a try

This measure fails if i add another customer row (a new customer c02) in customer table
add another row in Customer table
co2| 15m| 4
and then try

updated again. pls have a try.

Hey, thank you so much. It does the job well.
